# Impala last_value Returning Inconsistent Result in View

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala, hue

I have some data formatted in the following manner and I am having issues creating an Impala view with the correct output. 
Lets call this table *h_test_daily*:

```
+--------+-----------+-------+
| Tag_ID | Date      | Value |
+--------+-----------+-------+
| 1      | 7/10/2017 | 10    |
| 1      | 7/10/2017 |       |
| 1      | 7/9/2017  | 8     |
| 2      | 7/10/2017 | 20    |
| 2      | 7/10/2017 | 16    |
| 2      | 7/9/2017  | 9     |
| 3      | 7/10/2017 |       |
| 3      | 7/10/2017 | 10    |
| 3      | 7/9/2017  | 5     |
| 4      | 7/10/2017 | 13    |
| 4      | 7/10/2017 |       |
| 4      | 7/9/2017  | 18    |
+--------+-----------+-------+
```

I am trying to perform a last_value() aggregate on it using Impala (On a HUE server). Now performing the following SQL works fine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tag_ID, `Date`, Value FROM
(SELECT Tag_ID, 
`Date`,
last_value(Value IGNORE NULLS) over (PARTITION BY Tag_ID, `Date` 
ORDER BY `Date` ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as Value
FROM test.h_test_daily)
TAB
;
```

The output from this is correct. I get the last value for each Tag, for each date.

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
| Tag_ID |     Date  |    Value |
+--------+-----------+----------+
|      3 | 7/10/2017 |       10 |
|      4 | 7/10/2017 |       13 |
|      1 | 7/10/2017 |       10 |
|      1 | 7/9/2017  |        8 |
|      4 | 7/9/2017  |       18 |
|      2 | 7/9/2017  |        9 |
|      3 | 7/9/2017  |        5 |
|      2 | 7/10/2017 |       16 |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

So when I try to create a View using that SQL it does something weird. I start to see null values. Where it is getting the last value and now looking to see if it is null or not. This problem DOES NOT happen with a table. I am hoping I have done something wrong and that creating the view only shows it.

Here is the output of the view:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
| Tag_ID |     Date  |    Value |
+--------+-----------+----------+
|      3 | 7/10/2017 | 10       |
|      1 | 7/9/2017  | 8        |
|      4 | 7/9/2017  | 18       |
|      4 | 7/10/2017 | NULL     |
|      1 | 7/10/2017 | NULL     |
|      2 | 7/9/2017  | 9        |
|      3 | 7/9/2017  | 5        |
|      2 | 7/10/2017 | 16       |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

**EDIT:**
I have made a whole bunch of changes and I am still encountering the same issue. Here is what I have tried:

**Added column named mins**

As Gordon pointed out, my ordering was wrong. Each partition had the same order-by key. The table is data from a few sensors, it is updated every hour with an entire hour of data. So I added a *mins* column for each row. (This is unique when combined with *Tag_ID*)

Here is the updated table and SQL

```
+--------+-----------+-------+------+
| Tag_ID |   Date    | Value | mins |
+--------+-----------+-------+------+
|      1 | 7/9/2017  |     8 |   10 |
|      1 | 7/10/2017 |    10 |   10 |
|      1 | 7/10/2017 |    13 |   11 |
|      1 | 7/10/2017 |       |   12 |
|      2 | 7/9/2017  |     9 |   10 |
|      2 | 7/10/2017 |    15 |   10 |
|      2 | 7/10/2017 |    16 |   11 |
|      3 | 7/9/2017  |     5 |   10 |
|      3 | 7/10/2017 |       |   10 |
|      3 | 7/10/2017 |    10 |   11 |
|      4 | 7/9/2017  |    18 |   10 |
|      4 | 7/10/2017 |    13 |   10 |
|      4 | 7/10/2017 |       |   11 |
+--------+-----------+-------+------+
```

Now for the select statement and create view I ran into the same issues. Here is the updated SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tag_ID, `Date`, Value FROM
(SELECT Tag_ID, 
`Date`,
last_value(Value ignore nulls) over (PARTITION BY Tag_ID, `Date` ORDER BY 
mins ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as Value
FROM test.h_test_daily)
TAB
;
```

I then tried to filter out the `null` values in the sub-select, so I added a  `WHERE Value IS NOT NULL`. The problem with this, in the actual data set, there are about 40 different *Value* columns giving different information. So that column would get removed from the query even though one of the other values is *not* `null`.

**FINAL EDIT:** I contacted Cloudera's support team to clarify on this issue. They have gotten back and said this is an *Impala* issue. As they were not considering the `ignore nulls` argument on the create view. This issue is planned to be fixed in 2.10.0. Here is the Bug Thread: [Link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-5657)

Comment: You can get your current result without `last_value` using a simple *Group Max*: *MAX(Value) over (PARTITION BY Tag_ID,  `Date` 
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)*

Comment: That seems, to require the same `ORDER BY Date` ` that was causing the issue. However in either case, that doesn't help  me as the value may not be the maximum value.

Comment: I assumed there's only one value (plus NULLs) per ID/Date combination, but looking at ID=2 show two different values. Why is `2      | 7/10/2017 | 16` correct, but not `2      | 7/10/2017 | 20`?

Comment: So what I am looking for is the last non-empty and non-null Value for a given tag and date. So this is *not* a max or min, it is simply the last value. To give some more context, this table has more columns, where the tags are queried multiple times per minute.

Comment: Sounds like stock exchange data. To get only one row per id/day you don't need LAST_VALUE plus DISTINCT (btw, you might simply add `where value is not null` to get rid of the NULLs): `ROW_NUMBER...(ORDER BY yourTimestamp NULLS LAST) AS rn` in a *Derived Table* (which Impala calls *Subquery*) followed by a `WHERE rn = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with neither the view nor the table.  The problem is with your query.  You have `order by date`, but you are partitioning by the date as well.  So, the date is constant for the partition.

Sorts are *unstable* in SQL.  That means that when keys are the same, they can appear in any order -- and they do.  Why?  The reason is simple:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no default sort order.

The fact is, the query doesn't work in either context.  It just happens to look like it works in one case, but not the other.  You need another key to make the sort stable, so the same previous value will always be chosen.

Comment: So the problem lies in the fact that I am partitioning by the same thing I am ordering by? Shouldn't using `order by Value` fix the issue? What can I do to fix the issue? In this example I do only have three columns, where I am using two of them as my key.

Comment: @Hilmi . . . Ordering by a partition key is one cause of the problem.  The fundamental issue is that you have duplicate order-by-key values within each partition.  The ordering of the records is not well-defined and can change with each execution of the query.

Comment: Hey @Gordon, I have run into the same issue even after making the key values unique within the partitions. Please see the edited posted.